# :first-child only matches the first

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
var tab1 = $('.tabs a:first-child').attr('href');
alert(tab1);
```

.. matches only one although there are two `div.switch` on the same page. The second is down on the page, not in the same parent.

Edit: Basically my question is, :first-child should find all the elements, but it just stops after one like :first

Comment: what does `div.switch` have to do with it?  Your code is selecting html `a` tags that are first children within an element of class `tabs`.  Can you edit your question to provide more info?

Comment: `attr('href')` ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) will retrieve the value of the href attribute for the *first element* in the matched set.  Your set probably has all the items you expect it to have, but attr only looks at the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.tabs').each(function() {
 alert($('a:first-child', $(this)).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting one object at one time for getting attribute. `.tabs a:first-child` will select all `.tabs` and its first `a` element.

```
var tab1 = $('.tabs:first-child a:first-child').attr('href');
alert(tab1);

var tab2 = $('.tabs:last-child a:first-child').attr('href');
alert(tab2);
```

Delphist solution should also work.